# convention for counting days - "on the third day"

Tags: genesis, hebrew

Many times the phrase `on the Xth day` is used i.e.

> 22 When it was told Laban on the third day that Jacob had fled,

Genesis 31:22

Does this mean
a) Jacob fled + 2 days then Laban was notified
b) Jacob fled + 3 days then Laban was notified

Comment: someone having the paid version of Logos bible software may do a clause search to show all the examples of this. From what I know, it is means the same as third day or after three days.

Comment: See [inclusive counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Inclusive_counting).

Comment: I would have read "on the third day" to mean "(some time) on the third (calendar) day" in English (E.g. Jacob left Tue, Laban Told Thu.) rather than a measurement of 24 hour days only because that's the way English speakers tend to mean (since they are not usually using a stopwatch). "On the third day" in this case, could be as short as, say, 3 PM Tue - 6 AM Thu = 39 hours (i.e. less than 48 hours).

Answer (score 1):

Leviticus 23:

> 5The Lord’s Passover begins at **twilight** on the fourteenth day of the first month.

To count the days, begin with twilight, not sunrise.

Deuteronomy 5:

> 14 but the **seventh** day is a sabbath to the LORD your God.

So, the first day means the first 24 hours of the week.

Genesis 31:

> 19When Laban had gone to shear his sheep,

Presumably under daylight.

> Rachel stole her father’s household gods. 20Moreover, Jacob deceived Laban the Aramean by not telling him he was running away. 21So he **fled** with all he had,

Assume Jacob fled while there was daylight. Let's say at least 1 hour before sunset.

> crossed the Euphrates River, and headed for the hill country of Gilead.
>
> 22 On the third day Laban was told that Jacob had fled.

On the 3rd day means within 3*24 hours. Laban knew Jacob had left no more than 72 hours after the fact,

This mean Jacob fled + 2 days then Laban was notified,
i.e., between 49 hours to 72 hours.

Comment: The day starting at twilight/evening even predates the Mosaic Law: (Gen 1:5 "And there was evening, and there was morning, one day.") The idea is repeated in v. 8, 13, 19, 23, and 31.

Comment: One limitation of this approach is that it's using pieces of the narrative where _accurate measurement of elapsed time_ does not necessarily have to be the purpose of the author. It is not hard to find other instances where "round numbers" are used (not specifically in reference to days) that would thwart the reliability of such an argument.

Comment: "It is not hard to find other instances where "round numbers" are used." 
E.g.?

Comment: E.g. Ge 15:13 ("four hundred years" cf. Ex 12:40-41), 1Ki 6:37-38 ("seven years", from Ziv yr 4 - Bul yr 11 is ~6.5 yrs; compare to Lk 4:25 "three years and six months"), 2 Sam 8:4 ("1,700 horsemen and 20,000 foot soldiers"), 2 Chr 23:3 ("38,000 men"). My point is, it's hard to prove that the author is trying to be (very?) precise merely because he uses a number.

Comment: Compare to explicitly precise measurements, like Lev 23:16 ("fifty days to the day after the seventh sabbath"), Lev 25:50 ("his purchaser shall calculate from the year..."), Jer 52:28,29 ("3,023 Jews," "832 persons"), Ge 7:11, 8:4 ("second month, on the seventeenth day of the month", "seventh month, on the seventeenth day of the month").

Comment: You confused ordinal numbers with cardinals. Show verses where round numbers are used for ordinals.

Comment: The point is that unless the author is trying to measure elapsed time to the same precision as I want, it's dangerous to try to be very precise making my own calculations. There's a large margin of error. The passage the OP referenced is not trying to measure hours. The elapsed time could be anywhere from 36 to 72 hours. I can't just subtract the ordinal numbers and arrive at a precise number.

Comment: You said: "The elapsed time could be anywhere from 36 to 72 hours."

Did you even read the conclusion in my answer?

Comment: "no more than 72 hours" is an entirely factual answer. However, it didn't offer any sort of lower bound, nor did it suggest that the elapsed time could be _half_ that max value. The OP even asked "+2 days" or "+3 days", but "no more than" only half answers the question. If there's reasonable uncertainty, it would be good to point it out.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my answer?

Comment: I read (and hopefully understood—though I am questioning myself there) it before I commented. Day begins at twilight, day means 24 hours, assume daylight departure, third day = no more than 72 hours. Is there a lower bound in there?

Comment: Good point. I added.

Comment: So, if it's now in the middle of the day, the rest of this day up until sunset counts as the first day. But if it's now almost sunset on what we call Wednesday, the "first" day would be from that sunset to the sunset on Thursday, the "second" day would be from that sunset to  the sunset on Friday, and the "third" day would be from that sunset to the sunset on Saturday.

Comment: That's how I understand it. As far as I can tell so far, it is consistent with the OT usages.